# Use TFBuild variables in steps in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, msbuild, versioning, tfs-2015

I need use the $(Rev) property in an argument passed to MSBuild as part of my build process. I have defined `MajorVersion`, `MinorVersion` and `PatchVersion` as variables in my build definition, and I can use these in my arguments. If I pass an argument to MSBuild that contains this string: `$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion)-beta$(Rev:r)` it evaluates to something like `1.3.2-beta$(Rev:r)`, which causes problems. If I pass this argument: `$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion)-beta$(Build.BuildId)` then it correctly resolves to something like `1.3.2-beta204`. I also in time would like to replace the SemVer tag with a variable, e.g. `beta`, `rc`, etc., so I can adopt a git-flow approach to my builds and versioning.

Any ideas why $(Rev) isn't usable?

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse build number format [tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/define/general#BuildnumberformatTokens) with build [variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables).

`$(Rev:.r)` is a one of the tokens, resolved by the TFS build in runtime. You were correct to pass the resolved variable which encapsulates the build number format.
Alternatively, you can use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` in MSBuild with build number format `1.3.2-beta$(Rev:.r)`